# Use the previously trained model for further prediction in catboost

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-analysis, catboost

I want to find optimal parameters for doing classification using Catboost.
I have training data and test data. I want to run the algorithm for say 500 iterations and then make predictions on test data. Next, I want to repeat this for 600 iterations and then 700 iterations and so on. I don't want to start from iteration 0 again. So, is there any way I can do this in Catboost algorithm?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the algorithm for the maximum number of iterations and then use `CatBoost.predict()` with `ntree_limit` parameter or `CatBoost.staged_predict()` to try different number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First i create a predictive model in R using XGB. Now i want to
   build a regression model using CatBoost to improve the results**

   Superconductors dataset convert into training dataset & test dataset

> dataset_catboost20<-read.csv("train.csv")
>
> ```
> dataset_catboost20
>
> rows<-nrow(dataset_catboost20)
>
> f<-0.65
>
> upper_bound_catboost20<- floor(f*rows)
>
> permuted_dataset_catboost20<- dataset_catboost20[sample(rows),]
>
> train_dataset_catboost20<-permuted_dataset_catboost20[1:upper_bound_catboost20,]
>
> train_dataset_catboost20
> ```

2. **There are 28 independent variable & one dependent variable. Now i
   use the same formula as i use in XGB.Covert the formula into
   **sparse.model.matrix** both in XGB & Catboost. In XGB formula was
   working but in Catboost it show error.**

**Unsupported data type, expecting data.frame, got: dgCMatrix**

**Formula**

train_dataset_catboost2020

```
y_traincatboost20=train_dataset_catboost20$critical_temp

catboost_trcontrol20<-trainControl(method="cv", number = 5,allowParallel = TRUE,verboseIter = FALSE,returnData = FALSE)
catboostGrid20 <- expand.grid(depth= c(2,6,8), learning_rate=0.1, iterations=100,
                              l2_leaf_reg=.05, rsm=.95, border_count=65)
catboost_model20 = train(
  train_dataset_catboost2020,y_traincatboost20,method = catboost.caret,
  logging_level="Silent",preProc=NULL,

  tuneGrid = catboostGrid20,trControl=catboost_trcontrol20 )
```